# Proof of $T(X)‧Y=X‧T(Y)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to prove $T(X)‧Y=X‧T(Y)$, where $X$, $Y$ are vectors and $T$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$.

This equality is useful in proving the spectral theorem. My lecture note just simply applied the result. And I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: You can find a matrix $A$ such that $T(X)\equiv AX$. Then, it would be equivalent to proving $(AX)Y=X(AY)$.

Comment: Is the dot a scalar product? Then this is simply not true in general.

Comment: There should be an extra hypothesis... If $T: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ is defined by $T(x, y) = (-y, x)$, then we see that $T(1, 0)\cdot (0, 1) = (0, 1)\cdot (0, 1) = 1$ and $(1, 0)\cdot T(0, 1) = (1, 0)\cdot(-1, 0) = -1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That equation is the definition of a self-adjoint linear operator, with respect to the scalar product. That is, $T$ is called self-adjoint if it satisfies that equation for all vectors $X,Y$. Certainly not all linear operators are self-adjoint, so you must have been missing a hypothesis that was made in the text you are citing.